# kivy plyer gps not working after update to Android 12

Tags: android, kivy, gps, kivymd, buildozer

I build a simple Gps Apk using kivy, plyer compile the main using buildozer, everythings works fine but after update to Androud 12 can't get location. pls help thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work again shortly. A pull request has already been made. https://github.com/kivy/plyer/pull/665/files/1f84fcd24a44877522a8e2edf885c708e8158466

Cheers Rob

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31869144)

Comment: @Rob: Can you please explain, how to use this updated gps.py? Do I have to change the call of gps_location in my code after using the gps.py of HyTurtle? ... I don't know how to bring back gps-functionality in my code for android 12 ...

Answer (score 0):

As GPS stopped working for me since Android 12, I started searching for the error / solution. As Rob already mentioned by linking to github, there is a pull request, but until now, it's not integrated into a stable Kivy-update.
At the moment you have to add this github-link to buildozer requirements e.g.

```
requirements = python3, kivy, https://github.com/HyTurtle/plyer/archive/master.zip
```

Run `buildozer -v android clean` to remove the previously installed plyer version, than `buildozer android debug`.
Afterwards GPS-values are again available in android 12!

And this solution is - as far as I tested with android 11 and 7.1.1 - also backward compatible.